# Restrict Access To Some Commands

Tags: bash, command, block, alias, restrict

I'm trying to block a user from using some commands like rm , so I added these aliases :

exemple :

```
alias rm="printf 'not allowed'"  
alias alias="printf 'not allowed'"
```

everything works fine and they are blocked via terminal, but if He executes a ./script.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
rm a_file
```

the commands Are not blocked , is there any solution to this ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMD the Windows Command line program, your other tags are pointless. Try BASH.

Comment: This wouldn't stop them from calling `/bin/rm`.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest solution would be to protect the files that you don't want them to delete from them with permissions.

Comment: so it's impossible to completly block a command ? I also tried using lshell and still have the same problem :(